# Why does my reputation show more points for an answer than the answer does?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

My reputation page shows I've received 65 rep points for https://serverfault.com/a/484944/10380 but the answer itself only shows 5 points.  Is this a bug?  Or am I failing to understand how this works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer got **5 x 10 = 50 points** plus **15 points** for being the accepted answer, so the total is **65 points**. No bug.

Comment: D'oh.  For some reason I was thinking the answer should show 65 points. I know better; I blame it on the drink.